# JSX template literals for an inline style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to add an inline style on an element which includes variables.

Hard-coding the values works:

```
<circle style={{ strokeDasharray: "75, 25" }} ></circle>
```

But I need a way for both of the numbers in this style to pull from variables.

I've tried a variety of curly braces and backticks - I think I need template literals, but am not sure how the syntax works for them inside of the double curly braces that this inline style seems to require.

This one

```
<circle style={`{strokeDasharray: "${ percent }, 25"}`} ></circle>
```

fails with message: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, `style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}}` when using JSX.

This one

```
<circle style={{`strokeDasharray: "${ percent }, 25"`}} ></circle>
```

causes the build to fail completely.

This one

```
<circle style={{strokeDasharray: "`${ percent }`, 25"}} ></circle>
```

builds, but no inline style is added at all.

In addition to using the `percent` variable for the first numeric value, I need to calculate the second numeric value - it will always be 100 minus the `percent` variable.

Comment: style={} expects an object, so puting `\`{strokeDasharray: "${ percent }, 25"}\`` is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing here is that the code within the outer `{}` is pure JavaScript code (specifically, an expression [not a statement]). With the `style` property, you specify an object:

```
<circle style={yourObjectHere} />
```

In your case, you're specifying an object literal, just like any other object literal in JavaScript. So you have the property name, a colon, and the property value. Since part of the value is from a variable, you use the usual ways of creating a concatenated string:

```
<circle style={{strokeDasharray: percent + ", 25"}} />
```

or

```
<circle style={{strokeDasharray: `${percent}, 25`}} />
```

etc.

*(If you're wondering why I used `/>` instead of `></circle>`, it's because even non-void elements are typically self-closed in JSX. JSX isn't* quite *SVG or HTML or even XHTML, it's its own beast.)*

---

You probably  want to calculate the second number as well, as [Михаил Мишин shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62091984/157247), so with the above that's:

```
<circle style={{strokeDasharray: percent + ", " + (100 - percent)}} />
```

or

```
<circle style={{strokeDasharray: `${percent}, ${100 - percent}`}} />
```

Comment: Thank you for not only the full answer but all of the details. Knowing why I need to write things a certain way is very helpful for future tasks!

Answer (score 5):

```
style={{strokeDasharray: `${percent},${100 - percent}`}}
```

Comment: You were the fastest and upvoted - but TJ had a more in-depth explanation. :) Thank you!